# How to create redis custom master slave node with redis-cli cluster create

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, node-redis, redis-cluster

This is my first time to implement redis cluster.
Based on [redis-cluster](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial) tutorial i need at least 3 masters and 3 slaves, currently i have 4 servers

```
192.168.0.10 -> 1111 as master, 1122 as slave
192.168.0.20 -> 1111 as master, 1122 as slave
192.168.0.30 -> 1111 as master, 1122 as slave
192.168.0.40 -> 1111 as slave, 1122 as slave
```

Then i want to use the first three for master and slave, and the last one (192.168.0.40) for slave only.

How to do that? since in the command that i found in the tutorial i supposed to write it as

```
./redis-cli --cluster create 192.168.0.10:1111 192.168.0.20:1111 192.168.0.30:1111 
192.168.0.10:1122 192.168.0.20:1122 192.168.0.30:1122 
--cluster-replicas 1
```

Then how to add the fourth one? is something like this?

```
./redis-cli --cluster create 192.168.0.10:1111 192.168.0.20:1111 192.168.0.30:1111 
192.168.0.10:1122 192.168.0.20:1122 192.168.0.30:1122 
192.168.0.40:1111 192.168.0.40:1122 
--cluster-replicas 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is documentation on [adding a new node as a replica](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial#adding-a-new-node-as-a-replica)

There you can use the `add-node` command with the `cluster-slave` option.
The first argument is the address for the new node and the second the address of a random node existing in the cluster.

```sh
redis-cli --cluster add-node 192.168.0.40:1111 192.168.0.10:1111 --cluster-slave
redis-cli --cluster add-node 192.168.0.40:1112 192.168.0.10:1111 --cluster-slave
```

Comment: its calling another command right? do i need to restart the redis by applying your answer?

Comment: Yeah, those are additional commands to run after the `redis-cli --cluster create` one. You don't have to restart the cluster.